# Python files extractor on executable

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have build one executable file with python pyinstaller and need to
 keep some files within the executable when i execute the file it has
 to extract the other files to the specific path like installing a
 packages in specific folders.

i have done the following

```
  pyinstaller -F --add-data 'installation.zip:installation.zip' --onefile
```

but i don't have any idea how to extract the zip file in executable to
 the destination.

Comment: Use `sys._MEIPASS` to access the extracted files at runtime.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That actually helps thanks bro. i have shared my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the `exe` using this following code

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "installation.zip;installation" phpfilescopy_extract.py --console --onefile
```

> I have done extracting the zip file using this following code.
>   sys._MEIPASS - gives the temporary exe extraction path that i used to
>   locate the zip files and extracted from the path

```
def excute(self):

    global src
    #source = src
    dst = 'd:/destination'
    # sys._MEIPASS - gives the temporary exe extraction path that i used to locate the zip files and extracted from the path
    source = sys._MEIPASS + "/installation/installation.zip"


    if os.path.exists(dst):
        if source.endswith('.zip'):
            file_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source)
            file_zip.extractall(dst)
            QMessageBox.about(self, "Title", "all file's extracted")
        else:
            QMessageBox.about(self, "Title", "failed extract file")
    else:
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Title", "path not vialed ")
```